# Send Photo as Mail attachment is Missing

Tags: photos.app

I have just had my phone rebuilt.

I used to send a photo by clicking on the box-with-arrow below it and an app would come up to attach it to mail.

This has now disappeared ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Comment: Did you set up your email ?

Comment: try a hard reboot ! hold down sleep and home buttons till apple logo appears

Comment: Hi; yes i can send emails, and I can create an email then add the pic as an attachment. what I can't do is go straight from the image to email - there is an option to attach to a text, a note or Pbut the one that used to say 'mail' has gone

Answer (score 1):

When you are texting in the text box look to the left of the box and if you see anything there pull it to the right and it makes the camera icon visable. That is what my son showed me when I had the same question. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Or screen time settings. If that is on then it might be restricted.

Comment: thanks but it's not text I'm having trouble with - that icon is still there below the photo; it's the email one that has vanished